# Black screen menu when opening Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, ios-app

Maybe it’s the `SWRevealViewController` menu bug?

It doesn’t happen every time, but only in rare cases.

[image]

- App version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS version: Version 12.1 (build 16B92)